# How to create a field with a list of choices but store the index?

Tags: list, ms-access

I'm making a Microsoft Access table where one of the fields is a list of pre-made options. When I make a SQL query on that table it returns the values of the list as strings containing the spelled out choice. I would like to assign numerical values to each element of the list so a SQL query returns a number instead. How do I do this? I know it's possible because I have an access file with such a list but I'm unable to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to have your combo box use a query of the table as a Rowsource. This query would have the table unique ID in the first field and the field you wish to return as the second field. Then change the setting on the combo box for "Column Count" to 2. If you want to show both fields change the "Column Widths" value to 1"; 1". If you want to show only one field, change the value of one you do not want to see to 0. Now we you refer to this list in an SQL queries, it will use the ID field but show the user the string field.

Comment: Thanks for the input. An easier solution I found is in the list creation wizard, enter values for more than one coloumn, one of the columns being the numeric value. Afterwards you will be prompted to pick which column to use for queries.

Comment: Ah excellent. Glad that will work for you. I don't think I have ever used that wizard so thank you for teaching me something!